# Recommendation for Nexus 7 replacement

Tags: android, tablet

Recently, my Nexus 7 2013 (Wi-Fi only), died.

I am looking for a replacement, but things changed since I last required a tablet and I am not sure on what the next pick should be.

What I am looking for in Nexus 7 replacement is:
* Similar form factor (size)
* Ideally an additional memory card slot
* Relatively latest version of Android
* (If possible LTE support, but if not fine as well)

I looked into such tablets like Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e. It has additional memory card slot and Android 9 present. It is of different size, than Nexus 7, but that could also be fine.
I am a bit sceptical about Samsung in general, especially after the exploding phone battery fiasco.

Thanks for any recommendation,
Merry Christmas.

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention, that it needs to be affordable (Apple out of the question). Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e in my country I find a bit too expensive 439€.

Comment: Are you alright with Huawei options?

Comment: **Galaxy Tab S5e** would've been an option anyhow? It is way bigger in size.

Comment: @YisroelTech I was considering, but after you pointed benefits of Galaxy Tab A 8.0, I am not sure anymore. In comparison to S5e it is much more affordable. Are there any noticeable benefits besides size? Difference is almost 300€. It should be worth it.

Comment: @CaldeiraG are we talking regarding Huawei in general or some specific model? I had only one tablet Nexus 7 during my entire life, so I have no opinion regarding other companies and tablets that they produce.

Comment: @Eugene, the Galaxy Tab S5e is a flagship device and is WAY WAY more powerful, but indeed it is probably unnecessary for a workload that's coming for the very old Nexus 7

Comment: @YisroelTech assuming, that in following years technology will probably continue to evolve and change and I am not planning to change tablet in next 3-4 years at least, would Galaxy Tab A 8.0" still be enough or in that case it makes more sense consider Galaxy Tab S5e?

Comment: @Eugwne, it's hard to predict the future... but I'd say that the Tab A should still suffice. BTW, just pointing out that there are several generations of Tab A tablets, make sure to look for the **2019** one and not an older one.

Comment: @YisroelTech I understand. I guess last sub question would be. A noticed, that Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 2019 is just a bit more expensive, but still in an available price range. Is there any reason why you didn't suggest it? Maybe some pros/cons in comparison to Samsung Galaxy Tab A 8.0” (2019)?

Comment: @Eugene, you wrote **Similar form factor (size)**, which would mean you don't want something much bigger than the Nexus 7, so I thought 10" would be too big.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103545/discussion-between-eugene-and-yisroel-tech).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the [**Samsung Galaxy Tab A 8.0” (2019)**](https://amzn.to/30DZhtb) fits the bill (and is the only one like this from a non-Chinese brand.)

It's not big (while not 7" display it is only 8" display and the screen-to-body ratio is much smaller than the Nexus 7 because t has smaller bezels.) Has a Micro SD card slot. Has one before the last version of Android. And is pretty affordable.

Another honorable mention goes to the [**Lenovo Tab M8 FHD**](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/tablets/android-tablets/lenovo-tab-series/Lenovo-TB-8705/p/ZZITZTATB68) which is very similar, but specs are better and also the screen-to-body ratio is better.